# JQuery. Autosuggest. Keydown event in switch statement

Tags: jquery, switch-statement, keydown, keyup

I do not have enough knowledge in JQuery to figure out, where in this code below i'd mistaken. I'm not sure about `.live` handler. Anyway, this code stops on first `<li>` with added class '`selected`' on keydown event. I want it to check all `<li>` on each keydown.
Thank you for any constructive comments.

- suggest - input field, on keyup appears autosuggest list,
- result - `<ul id='result'></ul>`
- selected - `<li>`'s

Script:

```
$('#suggest').live('keyup keydown', function(event) {
    var search = $('#suggest').val();
    $.post('search.php', {
        search: search
    }, function(data) {
        $('#dropdown').html(data);

        switch (event.which) {
        case 40:

            var found = 0;

            $('#result li').each(function() {
                if ($(this).attr("class") == "selected") {
                    found = 1;
                }
            });

            if (found == 1) {
                var sel = $("#result li[class='selected'");

                // check if this is a last element in the list
                // if so then add selected class to the first element in the list
                if (sel.next().text() == '') {
                    $("#result li:first").addClass("selected");
                } else {
                    sel.next().addClass('selected');
                    // remove class selected from previous item
                    sel.removeClass('selected');
                }
            } else {
                $("#result li:first").addClass("selected");
            }
            break;

        case 38:
            //bla-bla
            break;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: jQuery JavaScript Library v1.7.1

Comment: What does #dropdown refer to in relation to #result?

Comment: #dropdown - div for #result output

Comment: can you post this in a js fiddel with an example resource of your ajax request. Will be easier to debug and assist that way, thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes:

1. To check if an element has a class, never use `.attr("class") ==`.  If the element has more than one class, or the attribute is poorly formatted, this will never match.  jQuery provides `.hasClass()` for just this purpose.  `$(this).hasClass('selected')`
2. You don't need to loop through each element with `.each()` to see if one has a class.  You can call `.hasClass()` on the whole group.
3. Likewise to select an element with a class, use `.myclass` not `[class="myclass"]`.  This is for similar reasons as point #1.  `var sel = $("#result li.selected");`
4. To see if an element is the last sibling, don't use `sel.next().text() == ''`.  This will end up calling `text()` on an undefined object (because there is none).  Instead use `.length` to see if there is/isn't a next object: `sel.next().length == 0`
5. You probably don't need to search when the up/down keys are pressed.  I would put an `if/then` statement to do the up/down stuff separate from searching.
6. Your up and down code will be very similar.  Instead of using a `case` for each key, use the same code for both, but modify it slightly depending on whether you have up or down.
7. Using `keyup` and `keydown` will cause your up/down keys to fire twice, meaning your user will only be able to step 2 or more items at a time.  Either just use one, or only respond to one for the up/down code using `if(event.type == 'keydown') {`

With all of that, everything seems to work ok:

http://jsfiddle.net/wgQE5/2/

Is there some other behavior you were wanting?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xos2MnVxe-c - best expression of my emotions now:)

Comment: I've made it quick cause of already done `if(event.type == 'keydown') {` structure before.

Answer (score 0):

Also instead of reinventing the wheel you may want to simply check out:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Or

http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/

If for no other reason as a source to look through the code to see what is going on and how you can modify for your own needs.